# Creating a data frame of unequal lengths

Tags: r

I apologize if this is a duplicate question.

```
col1 = c(1:8)
col2 = c("a", "b", "c")
```

I want to create a data frame that will have 8 rows, and col2 becomes a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b and it will automatically adjust if I change the number 8. Without having to do this:

```
final_result = data.frame(
col1 = col1,
col2 = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b")
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: `rep(c('a','b','c'),len=8)`

Comment: Note that this "recycling" occurs naturally and without action if the number of repeats is a whole number. That is, `data.frame(a=1:8, b=c('a','b'))` works because the len-2 vector is repeated perfectly; `data.frame(a=1:8, b=c('a','b','c'))` fails because it does not.